# How to properly logout of a Java EE 6 Web Application after logging in

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, servlets, logout

A pretty simple requirement. After logging into web J2EE 6 application, how can I have the user logout again?

Most (all?) the books and tutorials I have seen show how to add a login/loginerror page to their application and demonstrate the use of security principals/roles/realms etc using the "j_security_check" method - all good. But then it's not clear how to give the user the power to logout. Indeed, how can I force a logout after, say, the session times out, etc?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should have `logout servlet/jsp` which invalidates the session using the following ways:

- Before Servlet 3.0, using `session.invalidate() method` which invalidates the session also.
- Servlet 3.0 provides a API method `HttpServletRequest.logout()` which invalidates only the security context and the session still exists.

And, the Application UI should be providing a link which invokes that `logout servlet/jsp`

**Question:** Indeed, how can I force a logout after, say, the session times out, etc?

**Answer:** The `<session-timeout>` in web.xml lets you define the timeout value after which the session will get invalidated by the server.

Comment: Thanks Ramesh - that allowed me to put it together properly I think. One thing I picked up elsewhere was the importance of `return "/index?faces-redirect=true";` - this is needed to break the existing session and any client-side caching that may be going on.

Comment: For clarity Servlet 3.0 you  must do both logout() and session.invalidate()?

Comment: If you logout without invalidating the session, you ought to have a really good reason since it opens you up to information leakage. Users who log out intentionally expect to be treated as if they'd never logged in—especially if they're using a public terminal! 

See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet#Renew_the_Session_ID_After_Any_Privilege_Level_Change

Comment: Probably I don't understand good this answer: "in web.xml lets you define the timeout value after which the session will get invalidated by the server" I understand that this session timeout is the time that container waits after session is invalidated; and It's not correct, because this session timeout param is the time which container waits if it does not receive a request to can invalidate the session.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it programmatically using the [`logout()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#logout%28%29)-Method of [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html).
There is also a corresponding method for login in with username and password. These methods have been added in Servlet 3.0, so they're available in Java EE 6.

A timeout is a different beast and can be specified in `web.xml` as following:

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>30</session-timeout> 
</session-config>
```

The time unit is minutes.

Comment: This is available only since Servlet 3.0

Comment: Yes, but the question specifically mentions JEE 6, so Servlet 3.0 is fine

Answer (score 1):

Two step process -

1.create the logout page
 2.create a session bean with a logout method

**STEP A: The Logout Page**

```
<div class="mytext">
    <p>Hello #{userSession.username}, </p>
    <p><h:outputText value="It doesn't seem you're logged in anyway..." rendered="#{!userSession.userLoggedIn}" /></p>
</div>
    <h:form class="mytext" rendered="#{userSession.userLoggedIn}" >
        <h:panelGrid columns="2"  >
            <h:outputLabel value="Do you want to logout?" for="logout"  />
            <p:commandButton value="Logout" id="logout" action="#{userSession.logout}" />                                      
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

**STEP B: Session Bean Backing Code (snippet)**

```
public String logout() {
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
    session.invalidate();
    return "/index?faces-redirect=true";
}

public boolean isUserLoggedIn() {
    String user = this.getUsername();
    boolean result = !((user == null)|| user.isEmpty());
    return result;
}

/** Get the login username if it exists */
public String getUsername() {
    String user = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();
    return user;
}
```