# Loggin out from Form based authentication

Tags: jsp, servlets, security

Using servlet 2.3 is there a way to log a user out when he has signed in using form authentication. I know servlet 3.0 has this feature of logging out. What should servlet 2.3 users do for logging out ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just invalidate the session.

```
request.getSession().invalidate();
```

Don't forget to send a redirect afterwards.

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp");
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I was actually forwarding it and getting funny behavior. Redirection did the trick.

Comment: Yes, the session is still in the current request, but not anymore in the next request.

Answer (score 1):

Look here [Regarding Logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893727/how-to-properly-logout-of-a-java-ee-6-web-application-after-logging-in/10893823#10893823). It also explains the difference between

`Servlet 3.0 HttpServletRequest.logout()`

and

`session.invalidate() method.`