# Redirect not working after authentication and authorization

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I use a (Primefaces 3.5) logout button in my application that looks like:

```
<p:commandButton ajax="false" value="Logout" action="#{loginBean.logout}" />
```

The bean method looks like:

```
public String logout() {
    ExternalContext externalContext =
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
    try {
        request.logout();
        System.out.println("Logging out!");
        return "/mylogin?faces-redirect=true";
    } catch (ServletException ex) {
        System.out.println("Failed to logout!");
        return null;
    }      
}
```

The string Logging out! is printed correctly, but the redirect is not performed!

Only when I click the logout button a second time the login page is displayed again?

Why?

Regards,
G.Verhaag

Comment: Check this out it may help your context : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893727/how-to-properly-logout-of-a-java-ee-6-web-application-after-logging-in

Comment: Okay, checked that out, but still not working!

Comment: Could you please try update the page that you are trying to navigate like `<p:commandButton ajax="false" value="Logout" action="#{loginBean.logout}" update="newPageID" />`

Answer (score 0):

Change the return statement to

```
return "mylogin?faces-redirect=true."
```

Get rid of the slash.