# how to code in java for logout

Tags: java, servlets, logout

here is my code :

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
       HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
      if (session != null) {
            session.removeAttribute("FirstName");
            session.removeAttribute("pwd");

            session.invalidate();
      }
           response.sendRedirect("index.html");
    }

    }
```

After this what can i do ?
Any help would be appreciated ........

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893727/how-to-properly-logout-of-a-java-ee-6-web-application-after-logging-in)

Comment: what is the problem now?

Comment: You have to call it ;-)

Comment: map this servlet to an url in your web.xml...and btw session.invalidate() will remove all your attributes, no need to remove singles. Another note....saving the 'pwd' ina session attribute is as well a bad security practice!

Comment: have i  to make an jsp file for running this servlet ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better to logout using Cookies..Code for Cookies is :

```
Cookie loginCookie = null;
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
if(cookies != null) {
   for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
      if(cookie.getName().equals("uid")){
         loginCookie = cookie;
         break;
      }
   }
}
if(loginCookie != null){
   loginCookie.setMaxAge(0);
   response.addCookie(loginCookie);
}
response.sendRedirect("index.html");
```