# J_security_check session not ending

Tags: jsp, security, session, web.xml, j-security-check

I am a beginner trying to learn jsp, by creating a login page with the help of j_security_check.

In the following code from `web.xml`, you can see that everything in protected folder needs you to login to access it.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>protected/home.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Security Constraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/protected/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name> manager </role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Example Form-Based Authentication Area</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/protected/home.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description> An administrator </description>
    <role-name> manager </role-name>
</security-role>
```

However after entering the right credentials once, it just stays in "logged in" mode, and when I restart the server it does not prompt me to login again. I have tried using

`HttpSession session=request.getSession();
 session.invalidate();`

as well as

`<% 
request.getSession().invalidate(); 
request.getSession(false); 
%>`

and also the answers on  [How to properly logout of a Java EE 6 Web Application after logging in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893727/how-to-properly-logout-of-a-java-ee-6-web-application-after-logging-in) (Except the last one, as something went wrong regarding `FacesContext`)

but they all don't seem to work. So my question is how do I logout? Is there any problem in my structure? All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the login page to the actual login page:

`<form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>`