# Logout using servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am using this code to logout but still after logout I am able to hit url. Logout seems not working, I am calling this class when clicking on Logout image. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

```
public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if (cookies != null) {
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                if (cookie.getName().equals(PermissionDatabase.cookieName)) {
                    cookie.setMaxAge(0);
                    response.addCookie(cookie);
                }
            }
        }
        Redirect.sendToLogin(response);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly logout of a Java EE 6 Web Application after logging in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893727/how-to-properly-logout-of-a-java-ee-6-web-application-after-logging-in)

Comment: you are missing session invalidate and hit URL (as u mentioned i didn't understood what happening next) might be browser cache problem. So clear the browser cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
request.getSession().invalidate();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Can you, please try these.

```
1st :


 Cookie cookie=new Cookie("nameOfCookie","");  
    cookie.setMaxAge(0);  
    response.addCookie(cookie);



2nd :   

     for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                    if (cookie.getName().equals("nameOfCookie")) {
                        cookie.setMaxAge(0);
                        cookie.setValue("");

                        response.addCookie(cookie);
                    }
                }
```